# Camel inout with very long response times

Tags: multithreading, apache-camel

We have the following scenario that we would like to solve using Apache Camel:

An asynchronous request arrives to an AMQP endpoint configured in Camel. This message contains a header property for a reply-to that should be used for the response. Camel must pass this message to another service using JMS and then route the response back to the reply-to queue from the AMQP request. This seems like a textbook example for using the InOut functionality in Camel but we have one problem: The reply from JMS service could take a long time, in some cases several days.

As I understand it, if we are using InOut it would mean that we would lock a thread to the the long running service. If we are unlucky, we could get several long running calls simultaneously and in the worst case scenario it could be that all threads are busy waiting for replies thus clogging the system.

What strategy should I use for solving the problem described above? At the moment, I have created to separate routes: One that listens to the AMQP endpoint and forwards the message to the JMS endpoint. The other route listens to the replyto-queue for the jms system and would be responsible for sending the reply back to the AMQP reply-to. The problem I have right now is how I should store the AMQP reply-to between these two routes and I am not sure this is a good solution overall for this problem.

Any tips or ideas on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to wait for more than a minute for reply, it's probably a good thing to treat the reply as async. and create separate request and response routes.

Since you mention several days, you might even want to survive an application restart (or even backup-restore) to correlate the response. In such cases, you need to store correlation information in a persistent store such as a database or a JMS queue using message properties - and selectors to retrieve the correlation information back.

I've used both queues and databases for long time request/reply correlation information with success.

It's always a good practice to be able to fail over/restart the server or the application at any time knowing that any ongoing processing will take up where it left off without errors.

There is a cost in complexity and performance, but robustness is often perferred to performance.

Comment: Thank you for your response. We did choose to go with async style to solve this since it did not make sense to treat it as synchronous.